# Optionally matching symbol using lookbehind assertion

Tags: r, regex

Let's say I have some strings like these:

```
strings <- c("Robert: my name is Robert", "Michael my name is Michael", "Jack: I like turtles")
```

I would like to make a regular-expression query which returns exactly

```
[1] "Robert" "Michael"
```

I.e. names followed by "my name" and removing any potential colon sign after the name. My attempt was:

```
regmatches(strings, regexpr(".*(?=:* my name)", strings, perl = T))
```

Here I try to optionally match the colon sign by writing

```
(?=:* my name)
```

However, in this case the colon sign doesn't seem to get caught by the lookbehind assertion (or does it?), and I get instead

```
[1] "Robert:" "Michael"
```

Is there some way to change the expression inside the lookbehind assertion (or outside it for that matter) in order to remove the colon from the results?
Full code:

```
strings <- c("Robert: my name is Robert", "Michael my name is Michael",
             "Jack: I like turtles")
regmatches(strings, regexpr(".*(?=:* my name)", strings, perl = T))
```

Comment: It is a good idea to use `TRUE` instead of `T`, since `T <- FALSE` is a valid operation.

Comment: Is this the regex you're looking for:
`.*[^:](?=:* my name)`?


Demo: http://rubular.com/r/RrQAhhIs1j

Comment: @Kamuffel that seems to work, yes. Feel free to post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made you a regex which omits the colon:

```
.*[^:](?=:* my name)
```

A demo can be found here:

http://rubular.com/r/RrQAhhIs1j

Comment: @thelatemail No it will not. This is because you have to read the regex from left-to-right. With your regex you're basically saying: match zero or more characters except `:`. This will result in a match of all characters except the colon.